# отображение для конкретной группы пользователей в Django 4

Tags: python, django, авторизация

Никак не могу понять, как в Django реализовать свою панель управления для каждой группы пользователей.

Делаю dashboard для сайта. Есть 4 группы пользователей

- admin
- moderator
- operator
- clien

Сейчас я понял как отображать конкретный html, для конкретной группы, но это лишь голая страница, и другая группа пользователей может спокойно открыть чужой шаблон.

И я вообще не представляю, как ограничить этот функционал.

Т.е. Нужно, чтобы при авторизации пользователя из группы operator, выводился только этот шаблон, и адрес сайта был типа [www.адрессайта.ру/index.html](http://www.xn--80aaaofz0cjam.xn--p1ag/index.html)

и так, для каждой группы

Помогите, пожалуйста. Пол интернета перерыл, ничего похожего найти не могу. 2 дня убил на поиски и чтение документации, но ничего не понял..

Что есть:

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)

    msg = None

    if request.method == "POST":

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user.groups.filter(name='Администратор').count():
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("/")
            if user.groups.filter(name='Оператор').count():
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("/operator.html")
            else:
                msg = 'Логин или пароль - не верны'
        else:
            msg = 'Ошибка при проверке формы'

    return render(request, "accounts/login.html", {"form": form, "msg": msg})
```

Comment: покажите что есть на текущий момент. не с нуля же вам писать

Comment: @Sergey Tatarincev внес правку в вопрос. Но этот код относится к сравнению при авторизации, и при совпадении, он возвращает ридерект на страницу шаблона

Comment: Проще говоря, нужно так, чтобы index.html формировался исходя из конкретной группы пользователя. Если это админ, то index формируется из admin_template.html и тд

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема сделать проверку принадлежности пользователя к группе в теле view функции и в соответствии с результатом отдавать на рендер соответствующий шаблон? так как адрес страницы будет един для всех групп, пользователь не сможет открыть недоступный шаблон.

Answer (score 0):

Эта [статья](https://gadjimuradov.ru/post/django-permissions-upravlenie-pravami-dostupa/) станет отправной точкой для понимания:

В Django существуют permissions в django.contrib.auth.mixins

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin


class CreatePostView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'blog.add_post'
    model = Post
    fields = ('name', 'content')
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из самых простых способов - использовать токены. В параметрах `GET` указать

```
http://example.com/?token=ТОКЕН&group=ГРУППА
```

Где токен будет генерироваться на сервере и передаваться тем пользователям, которые через другой аналогичный `GET`-запрос авторизуются (куки на минималках).

Ну и можно исключить параметр `group`, и делать проверку пользователя по токену, какая у него группа и т. д.